# Is there a keyboard shortcut to Check In after entering checking comment in Team Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, team-explorer

When entering a check-in comment in Team Explorer, I'd like to be able to keep my hands on the keyboard and commit the change with the comment I've entered.

- The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key inserts a new line.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> brings up the Properties window

Is there a keyboard command to submit the pending changes while the cursor is in the comment textbox?

[image]

Comment: Does <Shift+Tab>, <Enter> work?

Comment: Gray, no, sadly, the Tab on keypress immediately moves focus to the hyperlink below the comment textbox.

Comment: I just tried it, I guess it works if you press shift+tab 4 times... not exactly a quick shortcut. Maybe someone else has a better solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to Check In after typing/pasting your comment.

Other Sub-optimal Alternatives:

*<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> 4 times to get there and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but it looks like you can also

*<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> sets your focus in the comment, and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> will commit it (presumably with the comment included).